# 2-way speaker system tweeter phase

Tags: audio, speakers

I'm in the middle of replacing stock speakers in the car with aftermarket speakers, and I've redone one door. The better difference in quality is very pronounced, but I wondered if I connected tweeter in the correct polarity so it's in phase with another mid-bass speaker.

I did some googling and found that I need to measure speaker system response and check if it's linear. Obviously, I didn't expect it to be truly "linear" from such a naïve setup, but any way, I put the other pair of speakers on the desk and played white noise and pink noise, while capturing spectrum on one polarity and opposite polarity of the tweeter.

For those who would like to know what are the speakers. Both are Audison Prima brand:

midbass: Audison AP4 (https://static.audison.com/media/2022/10/AUDISON_Prima_AP4_Tech_Sheet.pdf)

twitter: Audison AP1 (https://static.audison.com/media/2022/10/AUDISON_Prima_AP1_Tech_Sheet.pdf)

According to the manual, tweeter hi-pass filter is 2nd order 12dB at 3.5kHz, and mid-bass speaker has top frequency cut-out at 7.5kHz.

So, the question is, looking at the spectrum images below, which one looks correct wiring to you? They all have some dip at 3.5kHz, but when I turn polarity of tweeter around, I also get pronounced dip after 7.5k up to 10.5k. Please look at **red curve only**, yellow is instantaneous, I couldn't figure out how to remove it.

polarity in reverse (not as per manual), white noise:
[image]

polarity in reverse (not as per manual), pink noise:
[image]

polarity as per speaker manual (black stripe to minus of speaker), white noise:
[image]

polarity as per speaker manual (black stripe to minus of speaker), pink noise:
[image]

Comment: Please name the four images. Which one shows which configuration?

Comment: @winny I think it would defy the purpose of the question, as I hope that there correct and wrong frequency response plots. However, I'll put captions nevertheless.

Comment: I’d choose the reverse polarity one given the information you provided. One caveat is that most EQs (I hope you have a parametric one or a DSP) can happily adjust the frequency curve but only the ones with all-pass filters can adjust the phase response. Ideally, you should measure it too. Audiophiles disagree, but you hear dips and peaks in frequency response more than wild phase response.

Comment: @winny thank you for insight into this. I re-took all tests again, but this time not only flipping polarity at hi-pass output, but also at input as well. It seems that reversed input/normal output, looks consistent with normal input/reversed output, which probably does make sense. Both normal input/normal output and reversed input/reversed output results in 2 dips with hump in the middle. Do you think this is a result of hi-pass filter or phase reverse between two speakers?

Comment: That’s up to your acceptance level. I work in PA so mine are different.

Comment: The tweeter specs is much more sensitive (+6dB) than the woofer specs so the tweeter should be attenuated to match the woofer. The woofer should have a lowpass filter so it is not shrieking when the tweeter is playing. Your scope shows a 40dB difference and very low output from the woofer, maybe the woofer is missing an enclosure? The tweeter has a 2nd-order filter and if the woofer also has an even-orders filter then they create a notch at the crossover frequency if they are wired with the same polarity but create a +3dB boost at the crossover frequency if they are wired with opposite phase.

Comment: @Audioguru that's very good explanation. The setup is not complete, as there's a real 6.5 inch woofer, but it's connected to dedicated channel, that's why I didn't bring it into the test. I believe there's a hi-pass filter inside the car amplifier, which is only dedicated to mid-bass and tweeter. Do I need a low-pass filter on my mid-bass? If so, having 2nd order on tweeter, can I get away with 1st order on mid-bass? it will create 90* rotation, so will get out of phase of tweeter, which I'll be unable to correct, and will get out of phase of real woofer on the other channel.

Comment: Your biggest problem is that the midbass output level measured 20d to 40dB less than the tweeter Is the midbass tested without an important enclosure? Also, the midbass has two peaks around 180Hz and a reduction at about 260Hz. Your high frequency levels are rough because the misbass is playing is cone breakup shrieks while the tweeter is playing and the two sounds add and cancel at various frequencies. Add a lowpass filter at maybe 4.5kHz on the midbass.